# Find Max value and Item containing the max value for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset where each row represents an order having multiple items and quantities ordered for each item.
I'd like to know both the  item name and quantity for each row having the highest quantity.

My data looks like below :

```
Item1   Qty1    Item2   Qty2    Item3   Qty3    Item4   Qty4
SUV1     4       SUV2    5       SUV3    5       SUV4    3
SUV4     7       PLV4    3       PNC5    6        NA    NA
SUV3     5       PNC3    5        NA     NA       NA    NA
```

I was able to get the column name having the highest value in each row but not the item name when I tried the below code:

```
## 
library(tidyverse)

sodf_rank<- sodf2 %>% 
  rownames_to_column('id') %>%  # creates an ID number
  gather(dept, cnt, SKU1_Qty:SKU10_Qty) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(which.max(cnt))
##
```

I'm expecting to have a result like below :

```
RowID   Item    Qty
1       SUV2    5
2       SUV4    7
3       SUV3    5
```

Comment: After grouping by ID, you can `arrange(cnt)` from high to low then `slice(1)` the top value for each ID, which will return the three desired columns.

Comment: in base R you could do `merge(b<-reshape(df,1:ncol(df),dir="long",sep=""),aggregate(Qty~id,b,max))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

```r
df1 %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  unite(Item, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4) %>% 
  unite(Qty, Qty1, Qty2, Qty3, Qty4) %>% 
  separate_rows(2:3, sep = "_") %>% 
  mutate(Qty = as.numeric(Qty)) %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  filter(Qty == max(Qty, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   rowid [3]
#>   rowid Item    Qty
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 SUV2      5
#> 2     1 SUV3      5
#> 3     2 SUV4      7
#> 4     3 SUV3      5
#> 5     3 PNC3      5
```

---

---

Or instead of `filter(Qty == max(Qty, na.rm = TRUE))` in the last line:

```r
              ... %>% 
  arrange(-Qty) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

to get:

```r
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   rowid [3]
#   rowid Item    Qty
#   <int> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 SUV2      5
# 2     2 SUV4      7
# 3     3 SUV3      5
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="Item1   Qty1    Item2   Qty2    Item3   Qty3    Item4   Qty4
                        SUV1       4    SUV2       5    SUV3       5    SUV4       3
                        SUV4       7    PLV4       3    PNC5       6    NA        NA
                        SUV3       5    PNC3       5    NA        NA    NA        NA", 
                   header=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can separate `"Item"` and `"Qty"` columns, use `max.col` to get the maximum value from `qty_cols` and get corresponding value from `item_cols`.

```
item_cols <- grep("^Item", names(df), value = TRUE)
qty_cols <- grep("^Qty", names(df), value = TRUE)

inds <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(replace(df[qty_cols], 
              is.na(df[qty_cols]), 0), ties.method = "first"))

data.frame(RowID = seq_len(nrow(df)), Item = df[item_cols][inds], 
           Qty = df[qty_cols][inds])


#  RowID Item Qty
#1     1 SUV2   5
#2     2 SUV4   7
#3     3 SUV3   5
```

---

Or another option using `apply` row-wise

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
     inds <- which.max(x[qty_cols])
     c(x[qty_cols][inds], x[item_cols][inds])
}))
```